# Problems with Starman workers

Tags: linux, zombie-process, programming-pearls, starman, loadbalancer

We have the problem that many Starman workers are becoming zombies.
Sometimes more than 45 Zombies.
We have no idea why, because TTL is set by 5sec. actually the most zombies live more than 30 Sec.
the Problems startet 3 -4 month Ago. I think after the last updte.
All settings are from https://metacpan.org
4 Server working with it and all have the same Problem.
In the last few weeks th Problem was so high that all Loadbalancer going down and only a cold restart helps.

```
/etc/os-release
NAME="openSUSE Leap"
VERSION="15.5"
ID="opensuse-leap"
ID_LIKE="suse opensuse"
VERSION_ID="15.5"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Leap 15.5"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:leap:15.5"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Leap"
LOGO="distributor-logo-Leap"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8zFl.png)

```
Evaluate logs, create own error log but without result.
TTL checked, all settings are as stated in the documentation: https://metacpan.org/dist/Starman/view/script/starman
```

Comment: Please show the code that calls `wait`